# arbor.js dot-like bezier curves for edges

Tags: arbor.js

is there a way to draw arbor.js edges as bezier curves rather than straight lines?
The result I'd like to get is something similar to the graph one can get from graphviz dot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely - arbor.js doesn't do any rendering for you, you need to populate the `particleSystem.eachEdge` function yourself - so just replace the `.line()` call from the demos with `.bezierCurveTo()`. You will presumably need to do some work to calculate the other parameters to make the results look good.